# Analyze a string of characters in java for format A^nB^n

Tags: java

I have a string of characters with As and Bs that I need to analyze for a Language A^nB^n. I can use the following code to work most of the time but when there is a letter that is not an "A" or "B" it may still return true, for example: AABACABAA should not be true, but it says it is.  AABB is true; AABBAABB is not true.  I have to use stacks and am not allowed to use counting.

```
public static boolean isL2(String line){
        // set up empty stacks
        Stack L2Stack = new Stack();

        // initialize loop counter
        int i = 0;
        int n = line.length();

        /* Push all 'A's to a_stack */
        while ((i < line.length()) && (line.charAt(i) == 'A')) {
            char ch = line.charAt(i);
            L2Stack.push(ch);
            i++;
        }

        /* Pop an 'A' for each consecutive 'B' */
        while ((i < line.length()) && (line.charAt(i) == 'B')) {
             if (!L2Stack.empty()){
                    L2Stack.pop();
                        i++;
             }
             else
                return false;
        }

        if (i == n && !L2Stack.empty()){
                return false; // more As than Bs
        }
        if (i != n && L2Stack.empty()){
                return false;  //more Bs than As
        }else
            return true;

  }
```

Comment: You never reset your `i` variable back to 0 between your two loops.  Perhaps this is your problem?

Comment: If i reset the i then it will keep reading the same character

Comment: @MichaelParker - `i` appears to be a string index. This doesn't appear to be the problem

Comment: I think if you have a letter that is not A or B, you need to return false immediately. That breaks the format, no?

Comment: so something like :                                                        if (line.charAt(i) !='A' || !='B')                                        return false;

Comment: Oh, yes, my bad.  I'm having some difficulty analyzing your requirements.  Could you perhaps edit your question with example inputs and what the desired output is for each of them?

Comment: yeah, that, in each while loop, written correctly though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (i != n && L2Stack.empty()) {
    return false;  //more Bs than As
}
```

Should be

```
if (i != n) {
    return false;
}
```

Since if you haven't finished reading all the characters, you can't return true, regardless of whether or not the stack is empty.

I'm assuming that AAABBBA should return false.

That change would also handle illegal characters.